# Is it possible to process pieces of code simultaneously instead of sequentially

Tags: python, asynchronous

If I have:

```
def EventCheck():

    if cond_1 == True:
        do small action

    if cond_2 == True:
         do small action

    if cond_3 == True:
         for i in range(20):
            do longer action multiple times

    if cond_4 == True:
        do small action

    if cond_5 == True:
        do small action


while true:
    eventCheck()
```

In my theoretical program normal flow control would be along the lines of fig. a in the picture

> [image]

Is it possible to fork the actual control of the program so if a specific event evaluates as true it then branches of and runs its function *while* the rest of the program continues on as normal? As in Fig. b above.

In my main 'event' loop, I have a condition that is rarely ever true, but when it is, I need it to go off an perform a semi-long task. Right now, it of course takes control of the program so while condition A is running it's code, none of the other main, frequently used events are able to be checked for.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html).

If the longer task is I/O bound (instead of CPU) there are some other solutions, like event-driven / async libraries and [threading](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html). These don't offer actual sequential code execution, but instead execute other code while I/O is being done. For a better understanding of choosing multiprocessing vs shared memory models like threading, read up on Python's [GIL](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock).

Comment: Multiprocessing seems to be doing exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: Note that there are a lot of new problems that come along with introducing multiple threads of execution in your code (that's putting it politely). The threading package and multiprocessing have the same API but do completely different things... Be aware that they bring different benefits and different headaches, and either one is suitable for your problem as it's described.